# HTML::FormHandler with DBIC update extra database column before update_model

Tags: perl, catalyst, html-formhandler

I'm using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler)  [(with DBIC)](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler::Model::DBIC) and I want to update a field on my model that depends on another field submitted on the form. HTML::FormHandler has a section on [handling extra database fields](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler::Manual::Cookbook#Handle-extra-database-fields), and it says when a row is *created* to do this in before update_model:

```
before 'update_model' => sub {
   my $self = shift;

   $self->item->my_other_column( manipulate_value($self->field('my_field') );
};
```

This works when I add a new item, but not when I edit it. When I edit the item `my_field` is updated but `my_other_column` is not. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`before 'update_model'` works only when you add a new item.

> From docs: If there is another database field that needs to be updated
>   when a row is **created**, **add** an attribute to the form, and then process it with `before 'update_model'`.

Try `around 'update_model'`.